# If $X$ is a nonempty subset of $R$, show that $C(X) = \{c \in R \mid cx = xc \;\;\forall x \in X\}$ is a subring of $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We have to the $4$ step check in order to check if it is a subring.

$0 \in C(X)$ because $x\cdot0 = 0\cdot x$.

$1 \in C(X)$ because $x\cdot 1 = 1\cdot x$.

Now we have to prove closure with two operations. Let $c_1 \in C(X)$ and $c_2 \in C(X)$. Now, we know that,

\begin{align}
    c_1 &= xc_1x^{-1} \\
    c_2 &= xc_2x^{-1}
\end{align}
So, we must show that $c_1 + c_2 \in C(X)$. Now,

\begin{align*}
    c_1 + c_2 &= xc_1x^{-1} + xc_2x^{-1} \\
    &= x(c_1x^{-1} + c_2x^{-1}) \\
    &= x(c_1 + c_2)x^{-1}
\end{align*}
Therefore, $c_1 + c_2$ is in $C(X)$. We must also show that $c_1c_2$ is in $C(X)$. Now, 
\begin{align*}
    c_1c_2 &= xc_1x^{-1}xc_2x^{-1} \\
    &= xc_1c_2x^{-1}
\end{align*}
Hence, $c_1c_2$ is in $C(X)$. 
Since all four conditions for subring has been passed, the ring $C(X)$ is a subring of $R$.

This was my solution but apparently it is wrong. How do we solve this problem?

Comment: To show that a subset is a subring, it suffices to show that it is closed under subtraction and multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

For sums: Let $x$ be arbitrary, $c_1, c_2 \in C(X)$, then:

$$(c_1+c_2)x= c_1x+ c_2x = xc_1 + xc_2 = x(c_1+c_2)$$ using standard distributive laws, so by definition $c_1+c_2 \in C(X)$ because it commutes with every $x$.

You **cannot** assume $c_1^{-1}$ nor $c_2^{-1}$ exists as you do. What's given is it commutes with every $x$ and that's also the condition to be checked.

Similarly

$$(c_1c_2)x = c_1(c_2x)=c_1(xc_2) = (c_1x)c_2 = (xc_1)c_2 = x(c_1c_2)$$

for all $x$ and so $c_1c_2 \in C(X)$. And negation is easy too:

$$(-c_1)x= -(c_1x)=-(xc_1) = (xc_1)\cdot (-1) = x(c_1 \cdot (-1)) = x(-c_1)$$ or do substraction in one go as we did addition.

Comment: Dummit & Foote states that it suffices to show that a subset of a ring is closed under *subtraction* and multiplication to show that is a subring, akin to the "one-step subgroup test" where one need show $a,b\in G \implies ab^{-1}\in G$. Is it the case that it need only be closed under addition and multiplication?

Comment: @Math1000 I say something about it at the end now.

Comment: Thanks, I am just beginning to study algebra so I wanted to make sure my understanding was correct :)